# ActionScript 3 - Sound File Vs. Programmatically Created Sound

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

For basic sounds, such as sine waves or white noise, which is considered less processor intensive:  looping an .mp3 file or programmatically creating the sound?

My first though was that looping an .mp3 must be less involved than programming a sound, but after reading the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) and considering the primitive nature of these sounds i'm not so sure.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of CPU instructions per uncompressed sound sample is usually far less for decoding an mp3 than for algorithmically generating samples for most sounds more interesting than a square wave, especially if the actionscript interpreter and floating point math gets involved.

Comment: so would you argue that it's a best practice to load, play and loop an .mp3 file rather than generate and continuously play the same sound from code?

Comment: The best answer would be to find a way to profile and actually measure the difference on real code.  But the above is probably a good guess of the result.

Answer (score 1):

There is a well documented article on the adobe website about the sound manipulation: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/dynamic_sound_generation.html

It clearly depends on your needs, but looping an mp3 is quite easy. Generating a sound and looping over it seems a bit more complex even if it is feasible.

By the way, if you loop over an mp3 that is much easier to tweak the mp3 with an appropriated software. Just recompile and the updated mp3 will be played correctly.

M.

Comment: thanks for the link.  it seems that all sounds, whether they are programmed or loaded, are executed the same.  for a basic sound, such as a sine wave (which are quite easy to program), i'd like to know if the creation and processing of that programmed sound is less intensive than loading, playing and looping an .mp3 file that is a sample of a sine wave.

Comment: I don't have any data about that but in any way, playing a wave requires to load a large amount of data but no decompression, playing an mp3 requires less bandwidth but produces a CPU overhead for the decompression. Finally, generating a sound will probably the most optimized solution, but the cost is in development / maintenance time. HIH